# Calling JavaScript from within CSS :hover

Tags: javascript, css, hover, method-call

Is there any way that I can call a `JavaScript` function via css?

For example, from this `:hover` style:

```
.first-nav li a:hover,
.first-nav li.hover a {
    margin:-3px 0 -1px;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    background:url(../images/nav-hover.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

The `JavaScript` function I want to call is on an anchor `:hover`.

Comment: @Qutbuddin Kamaal: You should look into using a CSS library like jQuery or Prototype. They allow you to perform queries using CSS selectors, and you can set a single event handler to many elements instantly (which looks to me like what you are trying to do).

Comment: uh, I meant JS library (and it's too late to edit now lol)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, you can't trigger JavaScript from CSS directly.

What you *can* do is use CSS selectors to find the elements you want to watch in this way, and then watch for mouse events. The standard events are `mouseover` and `mouseout`, but they can be a bit tricky to work with because they bubble (you get `mouseout`, for instance, whenever the mouse leaves any descendant element). With appropriate logic, though, they're not to bad to work with, and in fact if you have lots of these, you probably want to use `mouseover` and `mouseout` rather than the alternative below because you can set them on just a parent container and then work out which descendant element is involved, which can be simpler in some cases (and more complicated in others).

IE provides `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` which are much easier to work with because they don't bubble, but (of course) IE-specific. These are so handy that frameworks are starting to support them even in browsers that don't; [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com) provide them, for instance, and I wouldn't be too surprised if some other frameworks do as well. jQuery also provides the handy [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function, which would be very close to what you want:

```
// jQuery
$(".first-nav li a").hover(
    function(event) {
        // The mouse has entered the element, can reference the element via 'this'
    },
    function (event) {
        // The mouse has left the element, can reference the element via 'this'
    }
 );
```

...which is really just a shortcut for setting up `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers, but still, wonderfully concise.

In Prototype it's quite similar:

```
// Prototype
$$(".first-nav li a")
    .invoke("observe", "mouseenter", function(event) {
        // The mouse has entered the element, can reference the element via 'this'
    })
    .invoke("observe", "mouseleave", function(event) {
        // The mouse has left the element, can reference the element via 'this'
    });
```

(OT: In both cases, I've used anonymous inline function expressions just to avoid giving the impression you have to use named functions. I *always* recommend using named functions in production code, though.)

Answer (score 5):

No.

(Well, Microsoft Expressions and Mozilla Bindings might allow it, but both are proprietary and should be avoided)

Assign your event handlers from JavaScript. Libraries such as YUI and jQuery allow you to pick elements to apply them to using CSS selectors. [Event delegation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/event/event-delegation.html) allows you to handle events on elements without having to assign to each one explicitly (which is handy if you are adding them to the document after it loads).

Comment: +1. Expressions have been deprecated and will not work in IE8, mostly because of the absolutely attrocious impact they have on performance.  DHTML Behaviors still work, but they don't have the same performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can call it from javascript(it does the same thing). Below is the code on how to do it on JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").hover(function(){
        myFunctionInvoke();
    });
});
</script>
```

or if you have particular anchor in mind just change the selector

Comment: I think you mean `.hover()` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: @Mathias Bynens that was indeed my intention I'll correct it now

Answer (score 0):

Because it's more logical to do it from CSS.

If one wants to make links click on hover, it's an aesthetic quality and should be handled with CSS. For example:

```
#header_menu li a:hover{
    color:white;
    js:click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's both an aesthetic quality and, as such, it should be handled with CSS and a functional quality which should, as such, be handled with html and javascript.

And there is a very simple way to call a function on page load from within html:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score -3):

Actually. Yes you can. Just use javascript: in the background-url like this:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">BODY{background:url("javascript:yourFunction();")}</STYLE>
```

Not entirely sure if this will work though.

Cheers!

Comment: yes you can is not synonymous with not entirely sure this will work.