# Call a javascript function from CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if its possible in any way to:

```
.button{
width: somePX;
height: somePX;
}

.button:hover
 {
  onmouseup = "func(".button")";
 }
```

or something like that. I think it would be kinda cool?
instead of writing for each button onmouseup = onmouseup = onmouseup = onmouseup = onmouseup =.....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446598/calling-javascript-from-function-from-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery, you could do something like:

`$('.button').on('mouseup', function(){...});`

CSS is a styling language, so you cannot modify the behaviour of HTML elements with it, only their style. If you wish to modify the behaviour, you can use JavaScript.

You could also use an Angular.js Class directive to change the behaviour of all elements with the `.button` class. But again, this is a JS library and not CSS.

Answer (score 3):

you can't use CSS to do it, but you can use something like jquery to use selectors to attach functions to elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy CSS doesn't have such kinda functionality. However you can use CSS selectors with jQuery.